# pi 4 won't boot with powered USB hub

Tags: boot, hub

I have a raspberry pi 4 with USBGear 4 port usb 3.0 hub. The USB hub is a powered type. If I boot the Pi system with the usb cable attached to the hub and without power on the hub, it all boots up just fine. However if the hub is powered and attached to the Pi via usb it does not boot. I either have to remove the power to the hub or disconnect the usb connection between hub and the Pi to get it to boot. Any help fixing this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Please confirm: the connection to the hub is to the hub's (singular) master port, and not just one of the normal ports.

Comment: I confirm that the connection of the usb master to the pi usb 3.0 is correct. In fact, because of the unique connector type it is hard to do otherwise.